# API Gateway configuration for S3 html content display

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to configure an API Gateway to allow access to HTML files stored in an S3 bucket.

I need to be able to see all the subfolders and objects within. I tried following multiple AWS guides, but none of them seem to work the way I want it to. For example, let's say I've got these objects in S3:

```
http://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/2022/06/index.html
http://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/2022/05/index.html
http://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/2023/04/index.html
```

To be accessible from API Gateway:

```
https://your-api-id.execute-api.your-region.amazonaws.com/test/2022/06/index.html
https://your-api-id.execute-api.your-region.amazonaws.com/test/2022/05/index.html
https://your-api-id.execute-api.your-region.amazonaws.com/test/2023/04/index.html
```

I reckon the best way to achieve that, would be using proxy+, however I have no clue how to configure it. Also worth nothing that all subfolders are created dynamically, so I cannot hardcode anything.

Answer (score 0):

[There's an official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) in the AWS Documentation for connecting an API Gateway to a private S3 bucket, leveraging the standard API Gateway's AWS Services Integration.

Below, I'll provide a more straightforward example of integrating a simple public bucket with a proxy path.

[From the official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html):

> To set up a proxy integration in an API Gateway API with a proxy
> resource, you perform the following tasks:
>
> - Create a proxy resource with a greedy path variable of {proxy+}.
> - Set the ANY method on the proxy resource.
> - Integrate the resource and method with a backend using the HTTP or
>   Lambda integration type.

In other words, you need to define a proxy resource.
To do this, go to the root of your API Gateway, select "Actions," and then choose "Create Resource." Make sure to check the "Configure as Proxy Resource" option.
Next, specify a greedy variable, which in this case is "{proxy+}": this variable will point to the HTTPS path of your S3 bucket and append the variable, something like:

```
http://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/{proxy}
```

That, in the API Gateway console environment, is:

[image: Simple Proxy Resource]

And the detail of the Integration Request id:

[image: Simple Proxy Integration Request]

Comment: Forgotten to mention that my bucket has public access blocked - probably that's why I am getting access denied, do I?

Comment: In this case it's better to use an AWS Service Integration with a properly configured IAM Role to let the API access the private bucket. There's an official guide to do this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Comment: I tried that already - this only works to access the objects in the bucket. What about all the other subfolders with objects? I cannot add each resource for every individual subfolder, it's impossible.

Comment: @xkzkx that's the usage of the {proxy+} greedy variable: it means that you can wrote "everything you want" after that path, and it will be passed to the underlying mapping (the S3 bucket in this case). You don't need to add a resource for every subfolder.

Comment: But using {proxy+} does not allow using AWS Service - you can only use Lambda Proxy Function, HTTP Proxy, or a VPC Link. None of these are useful to me if my bucket is set to private.